# Swagger takes both defined @JsonProperty field name and generates one automatuically

Tags: kotlin, swagger

I have a request class:

```
data class RegisterDto(
        @JsonProperty("first_name")
        var firstName : String,

        @JsonProperty("last_name")
        var lastName: String,

        @JsonProperty("email")
        var email : String,

        @JsonProperty("password")
        var password : String
)
```

Which in swagger UI looks like this:

[image]

As you see there are two fields `firstName` and `first_name` in the request. How do I make it only override the field name?

Swagger takes both defined @JsonProperty field name and generates one automatuically. How do I only keep the defined field?

I use `springdoc-openapi-ui` dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but data classes aren't supposed to use `var`s. You should change them to `val`.

Comment: just started working with kotlin, so thanks for the hint. 
sadly didn't help me

Comment: Can you try adding `springdoc-openapi-kotlin` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes! it helped. Adding the dependency worked for me. Just need to be careful with versions. On the first try they were apparently not compatible. Thanks! You could post it as an answer if you want

Comment: Great, I've done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields are included twice because Kotlin generates a getter for the field (e.g. `getFirstName()`), and `springdoc-openapi-ui` generates a field for both the field and the getter. When you don't override the name with `@JsonProperty("first_name")`, this is not a problem, because the library will detect that they are the same fields. However, with the annotation, it fails to detect this.

To solve the issue, you have to add `springdoc-openapi-kotlin` as a dependency. This will "teach" `springdoc-openapi-ui` how Kotlin fields should be handled (i.e. the getter should not be considered separately).